# value selected in first combo box should not appear in second combobox dropdown list

Tags: c#

I have two combo boxes containing names of city , Names are same in both and are retried from Database
I want that if I select Name in 1st combo box then that name should not be appeared in second combo box 
Tell me  where i have to implement code and what code i have to read

Comment: 1. At least tell us what GUI you use. 2. And what have you already tried?

Comment: Is this a winforms or web application? Can you show some code including what you have attempted?

Comment: its a C# desktop applicaion @Eugene Podskal
i am using Windows Form GUI

Comment: Is it WPF, or is it WinForms? Add the relevant tags to your question. It will greatly reduce the chances of being downvoted and may improve your chances of getting answers. But don't think that just adding the tags will be enough to [put this question into shape](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: I am new in Stack overflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using databinding, it is going to be difficult to remove unwanted entries ... you will most likely want to use unbound comboboxes and manually read the database on the 1st Combobox.SelectedValueChanged event.

When you read the database, exclude the rows you do not want.  Then you can add the items into Combobox #2.

Comment: Sir Kindly explain it throug code plz